# Windows Maximum Open Files per Network Session

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a program that utilises a PICK based/Multi-Value database system. The Database has some 800 tables with each table made up of a minimum of 2 files and most often 3 files. The system is a single tenant design and we have 700 odd clients.

We have a middleware service that acts as the intermediary between a web application and the databases. The middleware service sits on a server separate from the database files and so when the database engine opens the database files they are coming across a file share, eg \DBServer\DBFiles\ClientID\ etc.

What we are finding is that if we have the files on the middleware server we can open up at least half our clients on one server, but when they are located on the database server (glorified File Server) we seem to run into the "Maximum open files per session" of 16,384.

I originally thought it was a limit per share, but its per server.

My question is, is there a way to increase this limit? or does anyone have any way I can work around the issue?

Regards

Andrew

Comment: @joeqwerty2 Assume you mean add more file servers? in which case, that seems a little drastic.

Comment: If you're hitting a resource limit why would adding additional servers seem drastic? At some point you're going to hit the limits of Windows and physics, regardless of how much "tweaking" you perform.

Comment: So the limit isn't on the File Server side, its a Windows Networking limitation. So if I had one File Server It will happily serve 100's of 1000's of files to multiple different sessions. My issue is that I need to be able to open up more than 16,384 files on a single session,